# Getting the values of TextBox from a data bound ListBox

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, silverlight-4.0

I need to get the values from Listbox selected items. Note that, the data templates are in data bound. here is the xaml:

```
<ListBox Name="AppointmentResultsData" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="650" Width="480" Margin="24,0,0,0" Foreground="#CBF7FA" SelectionChanged="AppointmentResultsData_SelectionChanged">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Subject, Mode=TwoWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="30" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
                            <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Account.Name}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="28"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Start : " Grid.Column="0" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=StartTime}" FontSize="22" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="End : " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" FontSize="22"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=EndTime}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="3"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Location : " Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="4" FontSize="22"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Location}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="4"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="Status : " Grid.Column="0" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="5"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Status}" Grid.Column="1" FontSize="22" Grid.Row="5"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="    "/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
```

I need values of the textboxes in selection changed event.I have tried like this...

```
private void AppointmentResultsData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //SelectedEvent seleted = AppointmentResultsData.SelectedItem as SelectedEvent;
        if (AppointmentResultsData.SelectedIndex == -1)
            return;

        ListBoxItem currentSelectedListBoxItem = this.AppointmentResultsData.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(AppointmentResultsData.SelectedIndex) as ListBoxItem;

        if (currentSelectedListBoxItem == null)
            return;

        // Iterate whole listbox tree and search for this items
        TextBox nameBox = helperClass.FindDescendant<TextBox>(currentSelectedListBoxItem);
        TextBlock nameBlock = helperClass.FindDescendant<TextBlock>(currentSelectedListBoxItem);
        MessageBox.Show(nameBlock.Text + " " + nameBox.Text);
    }
```

But it didn't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it !

```
private void AppointmentResultsData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listBoxItem = AppointmentResultsData.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(AppointmentResultsData.SelectedIndex) as ListBoxItem;
        var txtBlk = FindVisualChildByType<TextBlock>(listBoxItem, "txtLocation");

        MessageBox.Show(txtBlk.Text);
    }




T FindVisualChildByType<T>(DependencyObject element, String name) where T : class
    {
        if (element is T && (element as FrameworkElement).Name == name)
            return element as T;
        int childcount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element);
        for (int i = 0; i < childcount; i++)
        {
            T childElement = FindVisualChildByType<T>(VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i), name);
            if (childElement != null)
                return childElement;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a list of class(MyClass) objects which you have databinded to listbox

Add a handler gesturelistener tap to the datatemplate

In the handler do this:

```
private void ItemClickedEventHandler(object sender, Microsoft.Phone.Controls.GestureEventArgs e)
        {                   
           MyClass clickedMyclass = (MyClass)((System.Windows.Controls.Grid)sender).DataContext;

        }
```

you have the object of the current selected item and you can access all the class variables. eg(StartTime etc.)

Comment: This is the databind for the listbox
**AppointmentResultsData.DataContext = e.Results.Where(s => s.Subject != x);**

here e is the **AppointmentsSearchEventArgs**

Comment: listbox the data bound is like this : 
 
void Appointments_SearchCompleted(object sender, AppointmentsSearchEventArgs e)
        {
   AppointmentResultsData.DataContext = e.Results.Where(s =>s.Subject != x);
        }

Comment: fine what you can do is store this search result in a list<MyClass> and data bind this list with your listbox in this way you can refer this list at later stage plus you get the object of MyClass for the particular index where you have tapped in the listbox

Answer (score 0):

Well you are casting it to the wrong type, this should work :

```
private void AppointmentResultsData_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {  
      var listBoxItem = AppointmentResultsData.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;
      TextBox nameBox = listBoxItem .FindName("nameYourTextBox") as TextBox;
      TextBlock nameBlock = dd.FindName("nameYourTextBlock") as TextBlock;
      MessageBox.Show(nameBlock.Text + " " + nameBox.Text);
     }
```

of course you need to add the Name to your `TextBox` and `TextBlock`

```
<TextBlock x:Name="nameYourTextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Account.Name}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" FontSize="28"/>
```

Plus I don't see any `TextBox` in your `XAML`.

Comment: I've named the textblocks but still unable to access! Giving **NullReferenceException** exception !

Comment: **var listBoxItem = AppointmentResultsData.SelectedItem as ListBoxItem;**
Gives selected item null but
**var listBoxItem = AppointmentResultsData.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(AppointmentResultsData.SelectedIndex) as ListBoxItem;
            TextBlock nameBox = listBoxItem.FindName("txtAccount") as TextBlock;
            MessageBox.Show(nameBox.Text);** 
gives me a selected item.Then messageBox gives **NullReferenceException**